# How do I internationalize/localize my rails plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, yaml

I wrote a [validates_word_count plugin](https://github.com/paulschreiber/validates_word_count). I would like to store the error messages in a YAML file so they can be easily translated.

My plugin's file layout looks like this:

```
validates_word_count/
  init.rb
  lib/
    validates_word_count.rb
    locale/
      en.yml
```

My YAML file looks like this:

```
en:
  validates_word_count:
    errors:
      messages:
        too_few_words: "has too few words (minimum is %d words)"
        too_many_words: "has too many words (maximum is %d words)"
```

However, if I call `I18n.translate('validates_word_count.errors.messages.too_few_words')`, I get this error:

```
translation missing: en, validates_word_count, errors, messages, too_few_words
```

How can I set up my plugin / locale so I18n.translate() works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two parts to the answer.

1. Use the standard directory layout:

```
validates_word_count/
init.rb
   lib/
     validates_word_count.rb
   config/
     locales/
       en.yml
```

2. In init.rb, add the following lines:

```
Dir[File.join("#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/config/locales/*.yml")].each do |locale|
I18n.load_path.unshift(locale)
end
```

Comment: Do you know how to do this in Rails 4? It looks like init.rb is no longer in use.

Comment: Rails plugins are no longer supported. You need to make a gem.